# std::bind(): bind lambda with rvalue reference as argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdbind

I am playing with `std::bind` and rvalue references, but I still don't figure out how it works, I have the following code:

```
class Dog {
 public:
   Dog(const string &name) : name_(name) {
     cout << "Dog::ctor" << endl;
   }
   string GetName() {
     return name_;
   }

 private:
   string name_;
};

auto bind_fun = bind([](Dog &&d){ cout << d.GetName() << endl; }, Dog("DogABC"));
bind_fun();
```

When commenting out `bind_fun()`, or if the lambda takes `Dog&` rather than `Dog&&`, the code run fine with expected output. When `bind_fun()` is left uncommented, the following compile time error:

```
test3.cpp:109:3: error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::__1::__bind<<lambda at test3.cpp:108:17>, Dog>'
  f();
  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:1749:9: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::__bind_return<<lambda at test3.cpp:108:17>, std::__1::tuple<Dog>, std::__1::tuple<>, false>'
        operator()(_Args&& ...__args)
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/functional:1758:9: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Args = <>]: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::__bind_return<const <lambda at test3.cpp:108:17>, const std::__1::tuple<Dog>, std::__1::tuple<>, false>'
        operator()(_Args&& ...__args) const
        ^
1 error generated.
```

My questions are:

1. Why `bind_fun()` can not be called(won't compile) when the lambda takes rvalue reference?
2. What is the difference between using reference and rvalue reference as arguments for the lambda here?

Comment: `std::bind` passes the bound arguments as lvalues, so it doesn't match the rvalue reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification for `std::bind` is rather dense. In brief, a plain bound argument (not a bind expression, not a `reference_wrapper`, and not a placeholder) is passed to the bound function as `std::forward<Vi>(tid)` where `Vi` is `TiD cv &`, `cv` is the cv-qualifiers of the call wrapper, `TiD` is the type `decay_t<Ti>`, `Ti` is the type actually passed to `bind`, and `tid` is "an lvalue of type `TiD` constructed from `std::forward<Ti>(ti)`", and `ti` is the argument passed to `bind`.

Applying this to your call, we see that `Ti` is `Dog` and `ti` is `Dog("DogABC")`. So `TiD` is also `Dog`, and `Vi` is `cv Dog &`, which means that `std::forward<Vi>(Tid)` is an *lvalue*, and the compiler complains because your lambda takes an rvalue reference parameter, and an rvalue reference parameter cannot bind to a lvalue.